# Does coding by convention prevent flexibility?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, convention-over-configur

Firstly, I'm 100% in favour of conventions and an entire team complying. However, I'm looking at frameworks (mostly various PHP but also Ruby on Rails and others) that pretty much enforce coding by convention. On the surface this seems like a great thing, so URLs are directly translated to `/controller/action`, for example. Models are named after DB tables, and the system knows exactly where to load all files from using a really simple autoloader.

However, we operate a white-label platform and what works for most clients doesn't necessarily work for others. Some may require a particular URL pattern, so we need to customise routes. Some may require that pages have a completely different layout to what other clients have, so we end up with an autoloader that is always checking whether zone-specific versions of files exist first, and fall-back to default if required. This makes development REALLY easy for us, because we just drop an appropriately named file into place and away it goes. But since it is the minority of cases where these are required, we find that the autoloader is spending an inordinate amount of time checking for files that are almost guaranteed to be missing.

To improve the situation a little, I was considering adding configuration over convention, so the zones that deviate from the norm would find the necessary *overrides* in a configuration file and will just go straight to the correct file, removing all of the existing-file checks, which I gather isn't terribly efficient (especially when some pages require hundreds of calls to the autoloader). I guess we would still be using convention by default, but allowing configuration to take over where necessary.

I'm interested to understand whether this is a practical or even recommended solution

Comment: Caching a "compiled" autoloader class/file map can eliminate a lot of those file checks; though it can have repercussions for "hot" changes to files

Comment: Indeed. We do cache a lot of information already and it can be a pain when something is updated, needing to clear caches. But the autoloader overrides are rarely changed so this would probably make sense

Comment: Certainly in a live production environment they should rarely change, and that's where the performance benefits are most needed: in development, you can set up an autoloader to build such a cache as well - but it need that extra step to check if there has been a new override file added, but can still use the cache as the fallback

Comment: Convention over configuration is really "use default configuration unless overriden". If your default config accounts for edge-case usage (optional files) the logical thing to do is optimize for the default setup without preventing flexibility. That doesn't mean configuration over convention, which is a road to verbosity.

Comment: @AD7six yes, this is what I was thinking. Default unless overridden. This surely provides us with a simple framework for day-to-day development, and a simple mechanism to override as necessary

Answer (score 2):

Rails works mostly that way. You have the convention, but everything comes with optional params that allow you to change things as needed. Have a legacy database where the unique id is not named `id` as Rails would expect it? Just tell Rails the name. Your routes are different? You can still write your own matchers. Have something to be done before a record is saved? Just hook into `before_save`.

For everything else things just work. You have a bit more work to declare all the things that are different, but you would have to write some code for that anyway.

We use Rails in a slightly uncommon environment, where we need to use data from an ERP system and use other systems that are not fully integrated with Rails, but it still takes a lot of work away at the core.

But obviously it only makes sense if there is a large enough core of things that all systems have in common, especially if you intend to write something completely from scratch. Adding flexibility that does not break things all the time requires careful planning.

Comment: OK, so Rails already does much like what I'm thinking about implementing. That's interesting, because I do see it lauded as a powerful, flexible and enjoyable framework to develop on. Good to know, thanks for the info

Answer (score 1):

In our application, we use a both configuration AND convention, but slightly more configuration than the latter (in some areas, its the reverse) and that's because you're almost always going to have situations where your conventions don't meed your real world requirements.

If that's the case, either your conventions are poorly suited to your architecture and clients or that your use cases are too varied for conventions to be of consistent and reliable use.

You can improve your conventions to suit your application requirements, but I think adding a dash of configuration to your mix can bring some order where you might be lacking. What I like about conventions is that it's akin to magic in some cases... But, it'd be tough working in a development environment of any reasonable size that was pure convention.

Your thinking is practical, I'd even recommend it, if the shoe fits.

Answer (score 1):

> “Programs must be written for people to read, and only incidentally for machines to execute.”
>
> ― Hal Abelson, Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs

You might not like what I'm about to say, but sometimes performance isn't the concern. I would stick with the solution which makes developers happy. If there's a simple convention to follow, you'd better stick to it, than create a complex configuration mechanism. There's no silver bullet here, but in my opinion, you will simply replace one convention (*place that here and that there*) with another (*place these configs here, and these - here*). Will it be harder to follow? Probably. It is in your hands to make it easy to use.

And, as always, keep your colleagues happy. Or they will find you. And eat you. And cover your code with nasty comments (that's the worst part).

Comment: No, I like that. I'm certainly not looking for people to tell me that I'm awesome and have the perfect solution already worked out. All opinions are valid IMHO. You're right, we need it to be easy for the developer to work with, and in many cases we have that right now. Thanks for your input